# Maven run test but "prohibited package name"

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit, web-applications

I try to test my app, i've insert into src/test/java my test class, maven run test because is its default directory, but throws "prohibited package name: java". How can i solve?

Comment: Change package name from "java" to something else.

Comment: already done but maven not run test

Comment: You should create some deeper package structure. The default package for java code in a maven project is obviously not to be used for classes. E.g. create a package `scr/test/java/my.package.main` where you put your main test. This structure should mirror the one in `scr/main/java`.

Comment: thanks a lot you saved my day!!!